# [UWP][XAML] How to get the size of the children on a canvas?

Tags: canvas, uwp-xaml

If I have some child controls on a canvas, what is the best way to determine the overall width and height of those controls? I've tried using ActualHeight and ActualWidth on the canvas but that appears to be giving me wrong values (too big).

Are there other properties, or do I need to iterate through the children working out the various values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas doesn't care the size of its children and there's no way to know their sizes without iterating through them.